# Insert elements in front of specific list elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have pandas data frame with two columns:

- sentence - `fo n bar`
- annotations `[B-inv, B-inv, O, I-acc, O, B-com, I-com, I-com]`

I want to insert additional 'O' elements in the annotations list in front of each annotation starting with 'B', which will look like this:

```
[O, B-inv, O, B-inv, O, I-acc, O, O, B-com, I-com, I-com]
' f o n  bar'
```

And then insert additional whitespace in front of each element with an index equal to the 'B' annotation indexes from the initial annotation: meaning inserting in front of each char from the sentence with index in this list `[0,1,5]`

Maybe to make it more visibly appealing I should represent it this way:

- Initial sentence:

| Ind | Sentence char | Annot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f | B-inv |
| 1 | o | B-inv |
| 2 | *whitespace* | O |
| 3 | n | I-acc |
| 4 | *whitespace* | O |
| 5 | b | B-com |
| 6 | a | I-com |
| 7 | r | I-com |

- End sentence:

| Ind | Sentence char | Annot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | *whitespace* | O |
| 1 | f | B-inv |
| 2 | *whitespace* | O |
| 3 | o | B-inv |
| 4 | *whitespace* | O |
| 5 | n | I-acc |
| 6 | *whitespace* | O |
| 7 | *whitespace* | O |
| 8 | b | B-com |
| 9 | a | I-com |
| 10 | r | I-com |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answer (list comprehension)

```
from itertools import chain
annot = ['B-inv', 'B-inv', 'O', 'I-acc', 'O', 'B-com', 'I-com', 'I-com']
sent = list('fo n bar')

annot, sent = list(map(lambda l: list(chain(*l)), list(zip(*[(['O', a], [' ', s]) if a.startswith('B') else ([a], [s]) for a,s in zip(annot, sent)]))))

print(annot)
print(''.join(sent))
```

`chain` from `itertools` allow you to chain together a list of lists to form a single list. Then the rest is some clumsy use of `zip` together with list unpacking (the prefix `*` in argument names) to get it in one line. `map` is only used to apply the same operation to both lists basically.

But a more readable version, so you can also follow the steps better, could be:

```
# find where in the annotations the element starts with 'B'
loc = [a.startswith('B') for a in annot]
# Use this locator to add an element and Merge the list of lists with `chain`
annot = list(chain.from_iterable([['O', a] if l else [a] for a,l in zip(annot, loc)]))
sent = ''.join(chain.from_iterable([[' ', a] if l else [a] for a,l in zip(sent, loc)])) # same on sentence
```

Note that above, I do not use `map` as we process each list separately, and there is less zipping and casting to lists. So most probably, a much cleaner, and hence preferred solution.

---

#### Old answer (pandas)

I am not sure it is the most convenient to do this on a DataFrame. It might be easier on a simple list, before converting to a DataFrame.

But anyway, here is a way through it, assuming you don't really have meaningful indices in your DataFrame (so that indices are simply the integer count of each row).

The trick is to use `.str` strings functions such as `startswith` in this case to find matching strings in one of the column Series of interest and then you could loop over the matching indices (`[0, 1, 5]` in the example) and insert at a dummy location (half index, e.g. `0.5` to place the row before row `1`) the row with the whitespace and `'O'` data. Then sorting by sindices with `.sort_index()` will rearrange all rows in the way you want.

```
import pandas as pd
annot = ['B-inv', 'B-inv', 'O', 'I-acc', 'O', 'B-com', 'I-com', 'I-com']
sent = list('fo n bar')
df = pd.DataFrame({'sent':sent, 'annot':annot})

idx = np.argwhere(df.annot.str.startswith('B').values) # find rows where annotations start with 'B'

for i in idx.ravel(): # Loop over the indices before which we want to insert a new row
  df.loc[i-0.5] = [' ', 'O'] # made up indices so that the subsequent sorting will place the row where you want it

df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True) # this will output the new DataFrame
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I did not explain well, but the table above is just used to show which string element is relative to its respective annotation. I actually want the result to be in the initially presented format, meaning annotations as a list and the sentence as a string.

Comment: I have found a solution that complements your result and gives me the desired output,  `df['sent'].str.cat(sep='')`, `list(df['annot'])` but I would appreciate it if you could suggest a solution with the initial `annot` and `sent`.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I completely misunderstood sorry... I don't know why I thought you wanted to do this with pandas... Here is an edit with list comprehension, and I leave the pandas version for reference.